# Do the return codes in Backbone.Event matter?

Tags: backbone.js

Do the return codes for the callback given to Backbone.Event matter at all? Is there a convention for them?

```
obj.on( "event_name", function () { return true; } )
```

vs

```
obj.on( "event_name", function () { return false; } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can really be sure is to check the backbone source. Here's the function that internally calls events:

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L303

It's a little hard to read because it's been heavily optimized. The actual call occurs on one of the five instances of `(ev = events[i]).callback.call`. In any of those cases, the return value is not used.

So it should be pretty clear that Backbone just discards the return value of the callbacks.